# Error code when trying to write to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, read-write

Basically I started Python a couple of days ago and wanted to create a program that could read and write files. Problem is I get this error:
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

```
choice = input("Open / Create file: ")
if choice == 'Create' or choice == 'create':
    new_file_name = input("Create a name for the file: ")
    print(open(new_file_name, "w"))
    text = input("Type to write to file: \n")
    file2 = open(new_file_name)
    print(file2.write(text))
    print("Reading file...")
    print(open(new_file_name, "r"))
    print(file2.read())
elif choice == 'Open' or choice == 'open':
    filename = input("File name or directory: ")
    file = open(filename)
    open(filename, "r")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Reading file...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(file.read())
    choice2 = input("Write to file? Y/N \n")
    if choice2 == 'Y' or choice2 == 'y':
        text2 = input("Type to write to file: ")
        open(filename, "w")
        file = open(filename)
        file.write(text2)
        choice3 = input("Read file? Y/N ")
        if choice3 == 'Y' or choice3 == 'y':
            print(file.read())
```

Comment: Notice that you have `open(filename, "w")` followed by `file = open(filename)` so what do you suppose that would do?

Comment: I proceded to delete file = open(filename) and now it wont even read files

Comment: It should be `file2 = open(new_file_name, "w")`. Get rid of the earlier `print(open(new_file_name, "w"))`

Comment: Calling `open` without assigning the result to a variable is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of issuing progress reports from your code is a good one, especially in the beginning stages. But it appears that you don't quite understand the difference between

```
print(open(new_file_name, "w"))
```

which is what your code actually does, and

```
print(f'open("{new_file_name}", "w")')
```

I believe the second of these is what you meant to do: it prints

```
open("myfile.txt", "w")
```

but what your actual code does is to (1) create an open file object for writing, then (2) print its type and memory location to the screen, and finally (3) *throw it away*.

So the first fix is to take out the `print()` calls, or at least reduce them to `print("step 1")` etc until you know how to do it properly.

The second fix is to not respond to the choice of Create by trying to *read* the file. If the user is creating the file then they are clearly not interested in the contents of any previous version. Your code responds to Create by *reading* the file, and that seems back-to-front to me, and in general programs should work the way that the average user, for example me, will think intuitive. Here is a correct way to do the Create bit:

```
choice = input("Open / Create file: ")
if choice == 'Create' or choice == 'create':
    new_file_name = input("Create a name for the file: ")
    with open(new_file_name, "w") as file2:
        file2.write("This is stuff to go into the created file.\n")
else:
    ...
```

This asks for the name of the file, opens it for writing, then writes some stuff to it.

Comment: Thank you very much for being patient and explaining it very well. I really appreciate it!

Comment: a small note on that mystery notation: `f'....'` is a "formatted string" that lets you template in information from other variables, so if you had a variable like `name = '...'` then you could do `salute = f'Good morning, {name}'`. In this case, however, since we're not templating anything in, you don't strictly need the `f` version of the string, and just `print('.....')` will work fine.